# rethinkDB getAll() changes the order of the table

Tags: rethinkdb

I started using rethinkDB.
When I call up the elements of a table with getAll, the order of the table is unfortunately changed, for example: [6,2,4,5] -> [2,4,5,6]

How can I use getAll () without reshuffling "the cards"?

```
function* extract(next) {
  const q = r
    .db("darwin")
    .table("roadbook")
    .filter({ date: date })

    .map((rb) => {
      return {
        //all: rb,
        missionTickets: r
          .db("darwin")
          .table("missionOrderTicket")

          .getAll(r.args(rb("missionTickets")))
          
          .coerceTo("array"),
        name: rb("missionTickets"),
        shift: rb("description").default(""),
        mateName: rb("meta")("summaries")("mateAlias").default(""),
        radio: rb("radio").default(""),
      };
    });

  return yield q.run(con, next);
}
```

greetings perry

Answer (score 0):

You cant use `getAll` and get the documents with a specific order. You have to use the `orderBy` function and order them by a field or by an index defined by you. In order to use the `orderBy` function with an index you have to replace `getAll` with `between` as a trick because `getAll` could not be chained with `orderBy` on an index. But this will work only on a single value inside `getAll`, not an array as in your case.

In your case where you have `.getAll(r.args(rb("missionTickets")))` you can only order by an non-indexed key, or you should change your data model in order to use `between` function and then `orderBy` with a single value rather than `r.args(rb("missionTickets"))`.